# Changing AJAX Params based on input values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two inputs that are tied up with an  On Change ajax call.

```
            <input type="email" id="lookupemail" style="width: 225px;" placeholder="john.smith@ufcfit.com">

            <select id="type" style="width: 150px;">
            <option value="member"> Member </option>
            <option value="lead"> Lead </option>
            </select>
```

The ajax call works fine, but it seems to not be passing my lookup type.. Did I format my variables incorrectly?

```
            <script>
            $("#lookupemail").keyup(function () {
              var lookuptype = $('#type').val();
              var lookupinput = $('#lookupemail').val();
              $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "includes/dbsearch.php",
              data: {lookuptype: lookupinput},
              success: function(server_response)
              {
                if(server_response != 0) {
                 // 
                } else {
                  //
                }

              }
              });
             }); 
            </script>
```

It passes:

```
      lookuptype:"conner@asdsafsdf"
```

Instead of..
          member:"conner@asdsafsdf"

Comment: Updated: I see what you are trying to to.  Try `{"" + lookuptype, lookupinput}`

Comment: @ochi That's not going to work.

Comment: @Juhana, I stand corrected, it will not work

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
data: {lookuptype: lookupinput},
```

Use something like:

```
data: {lookuptype: lookuptype, lookupemail: lookupinput},
```

When using an object for the `data` value of the ajax call you must supply `key/value` pairs. In your case, you're supplying a key = `lookuptype` and a value = `whatever-the-user-types-in-email-field`. You are not sending a `key/value` pair for the `email`.

On the server side you'd retrieve the data using the keys:

```
$lookuptype = $_POST['lookuptype'];
$lookupemail = $_POST['lookupemail'];
```

**NOTE**

If you intention is to make the `lookuptype` selected the key for your single `key/value` pair, then you must declare an object an manipulate it:

```
          var lookuptype = $('#type').val();
          var lookupinput = $('#lookupemail').val();
          var fData = {};                      //<<<<<======
          fData[lookuptype] = lookupinput;    //<<<<<<======
          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "includes/dbsearch.php",
          data: fData,                  //<<<<<<<=========
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass an object as the data parameter with a variable as the property name, you would have to do this:

```
var ajaxData = {};
ajaxData[lookuptype] = lookupinput;
```

So, overall, you should do this:

```
$("#lookupemail").keyup(function () {
  var lookuptype = $('#type').val();
  var lookupinput = $('#lookupemail').val();
  // Create the data object
  var ajaxData = {};
  ajaxData[lookuptype] = lookupinput;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/dbsearch.php",
    data: ajaxData,
    success: function (server_response) {
      if (server_response != 0) {
        // 
      } else {
        //
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Now that you know how to do this, let me tell you that it's a bad idea since the server won't know what properties to look for in the data that is passed to it. It's better to do what PeterKA suggests.